# Tengo una seria duda sobre porque no persiste mi formulario en la base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, formularios, entity-framework, symfony4

Este sería el código del formulario

```
$this->section->title = 'Create';
$this->section->action = 'BlackList';
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(BlackList::class);
$entity = $repository->findOneById($id);

// Check if collection is empty and create an empty form

if($entity->getProjects()->isEmpty()) {
    $project = new Project();
    $entity->addProject($project);
}

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity);
$form->add('projects', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Project::class,
        'label' => 'Project',
        'choice_label' => function ($project) {
            return  $project->getName() . ' - ' .  $project->getCountry()->getCode() . '(' .  $project->getId() . ')';
        },
        'choice_value' => 'id',
        'required' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true
    )
);

$form->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => ucfirst($this->section->action) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->section->title) . ' 3/4'));

$form = $form->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $entity = $form->getData();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    $this->addFlash(
        'success',
        'New '.ucfirst($this->section->title).' created!'
    );

    return $this->redirectToRoute('blacklist');
}

return
    $this->render('create.html.twig',
        array (
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'section' => $this->section,
        )
    );
```

Es curioso porque si utilizo la entidad de project para crear el formulario y listo la de blacklist si funciona el mismo código

Entidad Project

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProjectRepository")
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $domain;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Country")
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Lang")
     */
    private $lang;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Status")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $subtitle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Field::class, mappedBy="project", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $fields;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Campaign::class, mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $campaigns;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=CampaignThankYou::class, mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $campaignsthankyou;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $gross = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $duplicate = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $duplicategen = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $invalid = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $revenue = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $cost = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $valid = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $sold = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $fake = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Validator::class)
     */
    private $validator;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Tracking::class)
     */
    private $tracking;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $roi;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $capping;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $monthlycapping;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Header::class, mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $headers;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProjectCampaign::class, mappedBy="project", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $projectCampaigns;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ServerToServer::class, mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $serverToServers;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=GlobalBlackList::class, mappedBy="projects")
     */
    private $globalBlackLists;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $doi;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=BlackList::class, inversedBy="projects", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="black_list_project",
     *     joinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     },
     *     inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="black_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     }
     * )
     */

    private $blackLists;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->campaignsthankyou = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->fields = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->campaigns = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->headers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->projectCampaigns = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->serverToServers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->globalBlackLists = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->blackLists = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(?int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDomain(): ?string
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    public function setDomain(?string $domain): self
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?Country
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(?Country $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLang(): ?Lang
    {
        return $this->lang;
    }

    public function setLang(?Lang $lang): self
    {
        $this->lang = $lang;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?Status
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(?Status $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSubtitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->subtitle;
    }

    public function setSubtitle(?string $subtitle): self
    {
        $this->subtitle = $subtitle;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Field[]
     */
    public function getFields(): Collection
    {
        return $this->fields;
    }

    public function addField(Field $field): self
    {
        if (!$this->fields->contains($field)) {
            $this->fields[] = $field;
            $field->setProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeField(Field $field): self
    {
        if ($this->fields->contains($field)) {
            $this->fields->removeElement($field);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($field->getProject() === $this) {
                $field->setProject(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Campaign[]
     */
    public function getCampaigns(): Collection
    {
        return $this->campaigns;
    }

    public function addCampaign(Campaign $campaign): self
    {
        if (!$this->campaigns->contains($campaign)) {
            $this->campaigns[] = $campaign;
            $campaign->addProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCampaign(Campaign $campaign): self
    {
        if ($this->campaigns->contains($campaign)) {
            $this->campaigns->removeElement($campaign);
            $campaign->removeProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|CampaignThankYou[]
     */
    public function getCampaignThankYou(): Collection
    {
        return $this->campaignsthankyou;
    }

    public function addCampaignThankYou(CampaignThankYou $campaignthankyou): self
    {
        if (!$this->campaignsthankyou->contains($campaignthankyou)) {
            $this->campaignsthankyou[] = $campaignthankyou;
            $campaignthankyou->addProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCampaignThankYou(CampaignThankYou $campaignthankyou): self
    {
        if ($this->campaignsthankyou->contains($campaignthankyou)) {
            $this->campaignsthankyou->removeElement($campaignthankyou);
            $campaignthankyou->removeProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGross(): ?int
    {
        return $this->gross;
    }

    public function setGross(?int $gross): self
    {
        $this->gross = $gross;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDuplicate(): ?int
    {
        return $this->duplicate;
    }

    public function setDuplicate(?int $duplicate): self
    {
        $this->duplicate = $duplicate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDuplicategen(): ?int
    {
        return $this->duplicategen;
    }

    public function setDuplicategen(?int $duplicategen): self
    {
        $this->duplicategen = $duplicategen;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInvalid(): ?int
    {
        return $this->invalid;
    }

    public function setInvalid(?int $invalid): self
    {
        $this->invalid = $invalid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRevenue(): ?string
    {
        return $this->revenue;
    }

    public function setRevenue(?string $revenue): self
    {
        $this->revenue = $revenue;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCost(): ?string
    {
        return $this->cost;
    }

    public function setCost(?string $cost): self
    {
        $this->cost = $cost;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValid(): ?int
    {
        return $this->valid;
    }

    public function setValid(?int $valid): self
    {
        $this->valid = $valid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSold(): ?int
    {
        return $this->sold;
    }

    public function setSold(int $sold): self
    {
        $this->sold = $sold;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFake(): ?int
    {
        return $this->fake;
    }

    public function setFake(int $fake): self
    {
        $this->fake = $fake;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidator(): ?Validator
    {
        return $this->validator;
    }

    public function setValidator(?Validator $validator): self
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTracking(): ?Tracking
    {
        return $this->tracking;
    }

    public function setTracking(?Tracking $tracking): self
    {
        $this->tracking = $tracking;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoi(): ?string
    {
        return $this->roi;
    }

    public function setRoi(?string $roi): self
    {
        $this->roi = $roi;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCapping(): ?int
    {
        return $this->capping;
    }

    public function setCapping(?int $capping): self
    {
        $this->capping = $capping;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMonthlycapping(): ?int
    {
        return $this->monthlycapping;
    }

    public function setMonthlycapping(?int $monthlycapping): self
    {
        $this->monthlycapping = $monthlycapping;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Header[]
     */
    public function getHeaders(): Collection
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }

    public function addHeader(Header $header): self
    {
        if (!$this->headers->contains($header)) {
            $this->headers[] = $header;
            $header->setProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeHeader(Header $header): self
    {
        if ($this->headers->removeElement($header)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($header->getProject() === $this) {
                $header->setProject(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, ProjectCampaign>
     */
    public function getProjectCampaigns(): Collection
    {
        return $this->projectCampaigns;
    }

    public function addProjectCampaign(ProjectCampaign $projectCampaign): self
    {
        if (!$this->projectCampaigns->contains($projectCampaign)) {
            $this->projectCampaigns[] = $projectCampaign;
            $projectCampaign->setIdProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProjectCampaign(ProjectCampaign $projectCampaign): self
    {
        if ($this->projectCampaigns->removeElement($projectCampaign)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($projectCampaign->getIdProject() === $this) {
                $projectCampaign->setIdProject(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, ServerToServer>
     */
    public function getServerToServers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->serverToServers;
    }

    public function addServerToServer(ServerToServer $serverToServer): self
    {
        if (!$this->serverToServers->contains($serverToServer)) {
            $this->serverToServers[] = $serverToServer;
            $serverToServer->setProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeServerToServer(ServerToServer $serverToServer): self
    {
        if ($this->serverToServers->removeElement($serverToServer)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($serverToServer->getProject() === $this) {
                $serverToServer->setProject(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, GlobalBlackList>
     */
    public function getGlobalBlackLists(): Collection
    {

        return $this->globalBlackLists;
    }

    public function addGlobalBlackList(GlobalBlackList $globalBlackList): self
    {

        if (!$this->globalBlackLists->contains($globalBlackList)) {
            $this->globalBlackLists[] = $globalBlackList;
            $globalBlackList->addProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeGlobalBlackList(GlobalBlackList $globalBlackList): self
    {

        if ($this->globalBlackLists->removeElement($globalBlackList)) {
            $globalBlackList->removeProject($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDoi(): ?string
    {
        return $this->doi;
    }

    public function setDoi(?string $doi): self
    {
        $this->doi = $doi;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, BlackList>
     */
    public function getBlackLists(): Collection
    {
        return $this->blackLists;
    }

    public function addBlackList(BlackList $blackList): self
    {
        if (!$this->blackLists->contains($blackList)) {
            $this->blackLists[] = $blackList;
        }

        return $this;
      /*  if (!$this->blackLists->contains($blackList)) {
            $this->blackLists[] = $blackList;
            $blackList->addProject($this);
        }

        return $this;*/
    }

    public function removeBlackList(BlackList $blackList): self
    {
        /*
        if ($this->blackLists->removeElement($blackList)) {
            $blackList->removeProject($this);
        }

        return $this;*/
        $this->blackLists->removeElement($blackList);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Entidad BlackList

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\BlackListRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BlackListRepository::class)
 */
class BlackList
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Status::class)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $creationdate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Project::class, mappedBy="blackLists")
     */
    private $projects;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->projects = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(?int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?Status
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(?Status $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(?string $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreationdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->creationdate;
    }

    public function setCreationdate(?\DateTimeInterface $creationdate): self
    {
        $this->creationdate = $creationdate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Project>
     */
    public function getProjects(): Collection
    {
        return $this->projects;
    }

    public function addProject(Project $project): self
    {
        if (!$this->projects->contains($project)) {
            $this->projects[] = $project;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProject(Project $project): self
    {
        $this->projects->removeElement($project);

        return $this;
    }


}
```

¿Alguien que tenga idea de como solucionarlo y poder hacer el formulario y que persista con las dos entidades?

Cualquier duda la resolveré lo antes posible.
He estado ya varios días investigando pero nada.

Comment: ¿Te importaria mejorar el título de la pregunta?  Es que no se entiende (al menos yo). Puedes pulsar sobre el enlace [edit] en el pie de la pregunta para ello. Gracias. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas para obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Me equivoque con las prisas, mejor? 
PD: Es mi primerita vez.

Comment: Si, eso parece... no soy experto en symfony4 y no puedo ayudarte, pero ahora al menos puedo entender lo que pides y estar seguro de ello :-)  (no sabia eso de *persistir* por ejemplo, y buscando un poco he visto esta respuesta del so en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211317/how-to-persist-a-form-to-a-database-not-entity-in-symfony2 pero no se si te vale para nada, pero se parece a tu pregunta). Suerte!

Comment: Gracias, le dare un vistazo.